# Undefined variable on index.php

Tags: php, apache

I have been working on debugging a php site that implements a nav bar at the top of the page title navsection and a side nav bar titled sidenavcat. Upon run-time my navsection is displaying:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in 
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 25
> Hospitality 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 28
> Sustainability 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 31
> Events 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 34
> Press 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 37
> Catalogues 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 40
> Locations 
> Notice: Undefined variable: navsection in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/NOALivingWebsite/header.php on line 43
> Shop Online
> ```

The following corresponding lines in header.php are as follows

```
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'hospitality') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/hospitality.php">Hospitality</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'sustainability') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/sustainability.php">Sustainability</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'events') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/events.php">Events</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'press') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/press.php">Press</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'catalogue') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/catalogue.php">Catalogues</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'retail') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/code/locations.php">Locations</a>
</li>
<li <?php echo ($navsection == 'register') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/index.php">Shop Online</a>
</li>
```

Any advice you may lend will be greatly appreciate. Thank you for your time

Comment: Where have you defined that variable? `$navsection`

Comment: I am working behind some guys so I'm sure thats what needs to be added but should it be declared in the same .php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is rather than straight-forward. At the time where your `ternary` operator is executed, the variable `$navsection` is not defined.
A possible solution is to define that variable as [Session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable and access it like that:

```
$_SESSION["navsection"]
```

So your code will look like that:

```
<li <?php echo ($_SESSION["navsection"] == 'register') ? ' class="current"' : ''; ?> >
   <a href="http://localhost/NOALivingWebsite/index.php">Shop Online</a>
</li>
```

**Note:** Make sure that your `session` variable `navsection` is defined before the above check, possibly in another `.php` file.

You will need to use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) one as well in your html file. This should be used at the top of your html file like that:

```
<?php
  session_start( );
  $_SESSION["navsection"] = "register"; // Temporary fix.
?>
<html>
.
.
.
```

So that you can access your session variable.

Comment: Start the session in my index.php however where would I declare the variable?

Comment: That is up to you. You are checking a variable for a particular value. This value should be declared somewhere in advance of the check. It could be after the session_start(); in the same file or in another file. Either way, Session variable will be available. Depending on your design you choose what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help, still no luck

Comment: What do you want the variable $navsection to hold? Is it a hard-coded value or is dynamically set with a textbox or something?

Comment: I haven't seen it anywhere which is why I've been head scratching since the start of this endeavor. I need this page to display

Comment: I have edited my answer. This is a temporary fix though, that said the person responsible for the back-end should fix that by using the same session variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was definitely a doh moment. The solution was to declare the variable to the top of every page

Comment: Here is the solution applied <?php
    $navsection = '';
?>

Comment: Fair enough. Consider session variable if $navsection is set in another file.